Did Gödel admire Russell?
The way we view the erecting of Principia Mathematica and Gödel’s subsequent incompleteness theorem(s) must be very different now from how it seemed back then. PM was basically the first attempt to actually ground all of mathematics in a formal system, I think (which was actually type theory). Gödel’s incompleteness theorems directly reference PM in the title of the paper they were presented in.
I have never heard much of the background context in which Gödel became motivated to develop his incompleteness theorems. For example, did Gödel simply get exposure to Principia Mathematica since it was renowned - and, did he want to prove the incompleteness of certain formal systems, or was he as motivated to prove the completeness, and simply discovered incompleteness along the way?
Did he think highly of Russell’s work, or did he think it was philosophically misguided, somehow (since Gödel was a deep Platonist), and did he have a hunch he could expose a flaw in it?

This question deals mainly with the history of mathematics. It should be better asked on a a corresponding site.

background context: Hilbert's program. See history of modern logic textbooks: Grattan-Guinness, Haaparanta, Mancosu.

Gödel and Russell: see Kurt Gödel, Russell’s mathematical logic (1944), into: The Philosophy of Bertrand Russell.

For the correct link regarding G's Completeness and G's InCompleteness, see here.

And see Alasdair Urquhart, Russell and Gödel (The Bulletin of Symbolic Logic, 2016).
